# blockchain.info says password is incorrect, and wont allow me to access my BTC

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info, buy-bitcoins, wallet-recovery

I had a wallet ID through blockchain.info. I signed in, received my BTC from where I bought it, all was good.

I wrote down my 12 words for recovery and have them.

I changed my password to something that I know and logged off.

When I came back, it says the password was wrong and wouldnt let me log in (YES, I'm 1000% sure my password is correct).

I used the recovery tool and the 12 phrases and got emailed a new wallet ID...my BTC are not there.

My new password does not work for my original wallet ID.

This seems to be a common problem and I would really appreciate some help.

BTC REWARD IF YOU CAN HELP ME!

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! I have not used a blockchain.info wallet but, can you not just do a password reset?

Comment: There's no password reset functionality as blockchain.info doesn't know its users' passwords. The 12 words seed is the only information the user needs to restore its wallet. Has OP tried importing the seed into another wallet like Electrum?

Comment: Alcio - can you explain what you mean by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean the btc are not there, does a transaction show up when you used the phrase to recover? if so then it was probably stolen, if not, then you used the wrong phrase.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! As this is your first answer, remember to [be nice](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) and take a look at [How to answer?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Apparently the btc were sitting in an imported section of the original wallet id and doesn’t transfer over to the new one? Does that make sense? The phrase is correct because it creates a new wallet id just without my btc

Comment: Yes that makes sense. If you imported the address, it's not part of the hd wallet that is recoverable with the 12 words. If you imported the address, you may still have the private key of the address you imported...

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Can you explain what you mean by your last sentence? “You may still have the private key of the address you imported”? Thanks...

Comment: In your previous wallet you imported something right? Do you remember what it was? A paper wallet, something that contained btc? Those are known to be keypairs. An address (~ public key) for viewing and funding and a private key for spending.